# Running python on server, executing commands from computer

Tags: python-3.x

I made a login system with python. It works perfectly, but i want to run script on server or web. For example: Steam. Steam wants username and password to log in. So i wanted to do the same for my script. How can i do that?

My Code:

```
import os
import string
import time

version = "1.0 Alfa"

def login():
    print ("----------------------------------------")
    print ("                Login                   ")
    print ("----------------------------------------")
    k_name = input("Enter username: ")
    if os.path.exists(k_name + ".txt") == False:
        print ("Username not found.")
        create()
    else:
        k_pass = input("Enter password: ")
        with open(k_name + ".txt", "r") as f:
            if k_pass == f.read():
                print("Welcome %s!"%k_name)
                f.close()
                input()
            else:
                print("Password is wrong!")
                create()



def create():
    print("You using login system %s" % version)
    print( "----------------------------------------")
    print("|                 Lobby                |")
    print( "----------------------------------------")
    starting = input("To create user type R, to login type L").upper()
    if starting == "R":
        name = input("Enter username: ")
        password = input("Enter password: ")
        password2 = input("Enter password again: ")
        if password == password2:
            newfile = open(name + ".txt", "w")
            newfile.write(password)
            newfile.close()
            print("User created. Redirecting you to login.")
            time.sleep(2)
            login()
        elif password != password2:
            print("Passwords doesn't match.")
            input()
            create()
    elif starting == "L":
        login()
    else:
        print("\nWrong button\n")
        create()

create()
```

Comment: could you share your script you run locally to estimate if it is missing something to be executed on server ?

Comment: Edited the post. There it is :)

Comment: there are two options here: 1) either you want to run this script from the server just as a remote script - in that case you should provide creds to the script as command line parameters or config file 2) or you want to log in via web interface. I'll give a hint on option 1) in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script which you can run : python test.py user pass
it will save data if file not found and perform login

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, getopt
import os
import time

version = "1.0 Alfa"

def login(username=None, password=None):
    print ("----------------------------------------")
    print ("                Login                   ")
    print ("----------------------------------------")
    if username:
        k_name = username
    else:
        k_name = input("Enter username: ")
    if os.path.exists(k_name + ".txt") == False:
        print ("Username not found.")
        create(username, password, "R")
    else:
        if password:
            k_pass = password
        else:
            k_pass = input("Enter password: ")

        with open(k_name + ".txt", "r") as f:
            if k_pass == f.read():
                if not username:
                    print("Welcome %s!"%k_name)
                    f.close()
                    input()
            else:
                print("Password is wrong!")
                create()



def create(username=None, password=None, mode="L"):
    print("You using login system %s" % version)
    print( "----------------------------------------")
    print("|                 Lobby                |")
    print( "----------------------------------------")

    if mode:
        starting = mode
    else:
        starting = input("To create user type R, to login type L").upper()

    if starting == "R":
        if username:
            name = username
        else:
            name = input("Enter username: ")
        if password:
            password2 = password
        else:
            password = input("Enter password: ")
            password2 = input("Enter password again: ")

        if password == password2:
            newfile = open(name + ".txt", "w")
            newfile.write(password)
            newfile.close()
            print("User created. Redirecting you to login.")
            time.sleep(2)
            login(username, password)
        elif password != password2:
            print("Passwords doesn't match.")
            input()
            create()
    elif starting == "L":
        login(username, password)
    else:
        print("\nWrong button\n")
        create()

def main(argv):
    print sys.argv

    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print 'test.py <username> <password>'
        sys.exit()

    username = sys.argv[1]
    password = sys.argv[2]

    print 'username is ', username
    print 'password is ', password
    create(username, password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```